# Python　re.sub() の正規表現内でグループと`|`を使用した際、 置換させる文字列内でマッチした文字列を使用したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

`re.sub()` の中でマッチした文字列を置換先の文字列として使用したい場合、どのように書けばよいでしょうか。

ドキュメントに書いてある方法に従っていますが、うまく出力されません。

#### 現状のコード

```py
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tmp = re.sub('(a|b)', '\1\n', 'aiueobcd')
    print(tmp)
```

#### 期待する出力

```
a
iueob
cd
```

#### 実際の出力

[image: 出力結果]

#### 参考にしたサイト

[re --- 正規表現操作 — Python 3.9.4 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html)
[Python | 正規表現にマッチした文字列を新しい文字列に置換する(Pattern.sub, Pattern.subn)](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/regex/index10.html)

#### 環境

```
❯ python --version     
Python 3.9.5
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [Raw 文字列記法](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)を使うとよいのではないでしょうか。`tmp = re.sub(r'(a|b)', r'\1\n', 'aiueobcd')`

Answer (score 0):

metropolis さんのコメントの Raw 文字列の使用をお勧めしますが、Raw 文字列を使用しない場合は

```
#tmp = re.sub('(a|b)', '\1\n', 'aiueobcd')
tmp = re.sub('(a|b)', '\\1\n', 'aiueobcd')
```

としてください。